# Long, hot soaks in winter are a classic mistake

Tags: grammatical-number

Why 'a' is placed after 'are' ? Why 'a'  'is used for the plural 'soaks' ? Why it's 'a classic mistake' not 'classic mistakes' ?

Comment: The meaning of "a/an + noun" is "one example of + a noun."

Comment: But 'soaks' is plural...so how 'a classic faux pas'

Comment: 'faux pas' is singular though. Literal translation would be 'wrong step'.

Comment: To add to Duncan Drake's comment: *Long, hot soaks in winter are a classic faux pas = Long, hot soaks in winter are a classic **mistake**.*

Comment: No problem with meaning of faux pas..just want  to know why 'a classic mistake' not classic mistakes

Comment: There is no rule in English that the subject and the complement of the verb *to be* must agree in number. And you're only making one mistake (although you're making it many times).

Comment: "A" is not used for the plural *soaks*. "A" is used for the singular *mistake*. Yes, *soaks* is plural. And that's exactly why it does not say "a long hot soaks".

Comment: As to *mistake*, it's not *mistakes* for the exact same reason your mom and dad are your *family* and not your *families*. If you group several things into a single thing, the single thing is still single. That's the whole point.

Comment: Ok thanks.. but why did you close the question ..

Answer (score 1):

There is a single mistake mention: (taking) long hot, soaks in winter.

Even though one can take multiple soaks, they all represent a single mistake (repeated)

This is a fairly common construction:

> Bee-coloured flies are an example of mimicry

Even though many such flies exist, they just represent one example of mimicry.

In your example, if one would use the plural *mistakes*, I would expect there to be at least one other mistake:

Long, hot soaks in winter and ice-cold baths in summer are common mistakes.

Comment: Ok thanks.......